# How can i convert a date to an integer format?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, date-conversion

I have a column with a date and time. I need to convert that column into an integer format as shown in below. I tried with

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(date  AS DATETIME) AS BINARY(8)),1,4) AS INT) as Rowdate 
FROM Spend
```

but I am not getting the below format. Can you please help me guys.

Date:

```
2012-09-11 11:40:51.000
2012-09-11 11:49:59.000
2012-09-11 11:37:08.000
2012-09-11 11:58:44.000
2012-09-11 12:02:35.000
2012-09-11 11:47:08.000
2012-09-11 12:05:34.000
2012-09-11 11:53:42.000
2012-09-11 12:02:51.000
2012-09-11 12:06:09.000
2012-09-11 11:58:56.000
2012-09-11 11:58:14.000
2012-09-11 12:03:28.000
2012-09-11 11:53:24.000
2012-09-11 11:59:15.000
2012-09-11 11:57:08.000
```

Rowdate:

```
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
2012091116
```

Comment: Ok, I get the `20120911` part, but why the `16`?, and is the column datatype `DATETIME`?

Comment: @Lamak:Yes DATETIME is datatype.I am not getting idea about it,but atleast up to 20120911 is good it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Col DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(GETDATE()),(GETDATE()-1),(GETDATE()-3)


SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Col,112) + '16' --<-- Dont know why but here is your 16
FROM @TABLE
```

**RESULT**

```
2014030416
2014030316
2014030116
```

I have added this 16 because it is shown in your desire output but if you only want the part with 'YYYYMMDD' then the following will do the job.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ColumnName ,112)
FROM Table_Name
```

**RESULT**

```
20140304
20140303
20140301
```